# What is does the total transformation of painted objects look like for QGraphicsItem?

Tags: qt, paint, linear-algebra, qgraphicsitem, coordinate-transformation

Let 
`painter.transform()` = **P**, 
`self.transform()`= **L**, 
`self.sceneTransform()` = **S** 
`self.parent().transform()` = **P1** 
`self.parent().parent().transform()` = **P2** (and so on...)

When I draw a point without setting any transforms (not on `painter`, not `map`ing any of the shapes, and not on `self` (except what is done in other methods that control movement, scaling, & rotation).  Then how is this point, **x** mapped to its final position on the screen using the above matrix variables?

My goal is to understand this enough so that I can do this (at first, but I'm always doing QGraphicsItem stuff); which means I don't want to post a specific problem code (yet) since that won't solve my general lack of understanding necessarily:

- Drawing a selection rectangle works with the correct pen look & size, but upon calling `self.setTransform(self.transform().scale(Sx, Sy))`, the object scales correctly but the selection rect scales with it!  So if at the original scale there are 10 1x1 pixel dots making up a side of the selection rect, then upon scaling there are 10 Sx by Sy pixel dots making up a side and it doesn't look right.
- My solution intuitively is to scale the selection shape `QPainterPath` first (before painting), and do the painting of it in the identity scale.  This seems like a simple idea but is almost impossible to make work without understanding how the transformations involved are applied.

So please show me the matrix multiplication formula that maps a painted point to the screen, without any transformation consideration during painting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The situtation starts out like this: 
**I = identity** 
**To =** painter origin (upper left widget corner) to scene center (on screen) translation. 
**L = I**  
**S = I** 
**P = To**

### Object Movement

**Tm =** translation matrix of object in scene coordinates. 
(**Tm** in standard direction (+y = down, +x = right) 
Translation seems to be handled differently from below operations, since there is a `setPos(x,y)` func which has not relative transformation unless you invert the old translation and multipy that in as well.
If **T** is the total matrix of a sequence of the below operations then **S** will be: 
**S = T * Tm^-1** 
Similarly, 
**P = T * Tm** 
**L = T**

### Object Scaling

**Ts =** scaling matrix found by `QTransform().fromScale(Sx, Sy)` 
**L *= Ts** 
**S *= Ts** 
**P *= Ts** 
The result is applied by `self.setTransform(self.transform().scale(Sx, Sy))`.

### Object Rotation

**Tr =** rotation matrix found by `QTransform().fromRotation(R)`, where `+R` means clockwise. 
**L *= Tr** 
**S *= Tr** 
**P *= Tr** 
The result is applied by `self.setTransform(self.transform().rotate(R))`.

Mutliplication is done in the reverse order of conventional linear algebra, so make sure all you `m12(), m21(), m13(), m31(), ...` calls are transposed.

Thus painting a point `x = (x,y)` with `painter.drawPoint(*x)` without any extra matrix changes will result in **x' = x T Tm**.

Using that as a model, the defaultly painted selection box **b** gets painted as *b' = b TTm**,

So I want to remove scaling and rotation before painting and apply those to the `QPainterPath` first.  Based on our model, it seems like this should work:

```
p = self.shape()
T = self.transform()   # Local transform doesn't include translation in scene
p = T.map(p)
# b = p + pen stroke applied
painter.save()
painter.setTransform(QTransform().fromTranslation(self.pos()))
painter.strokePath(p, pen)
painter.restore()
```

That doesn't work, but the problem still seems to be with our model of translation only.  The scaling of the pen path works.

We forgout about **To**. Note that **To** is going to change around with QGraphicsView resizing.

So actually **P = T ToTm = T TmTo**.  **TmTo** only touches `dx = m31(), dy = m32()` of the matrix so, what we want to do is instead of `.fromTranslate(self.pos()))`, use `.fromTranslate(m31, m32)`.

Does it work?

### Yes, that works!